# JQuery finding an element is in a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with inputs on it and I am trying to get the index of the input that they are using.
For example

```js
$(document).on('keyup', '.inputs input', function(event) {
  var inputVal = $(this).val();
  var inputListVal = $(this).parent('tr').index(this); <!-- This is the bit thas not working -->
  console.log(inputListVal);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th><input type="text" name=""></th>
    <th><input type="text" name=""></th>
    <th><input type="text" name=""></th>
    <!-- I want this index if they are typing init -->
    <th><input type="text" name=""></th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Traverse up using `closest()`/`.parents()` to TR element. To get the index of *input* retrieve inputs in then parent then use `index()`

*Use*

```
 var inputListVal = $(this).closest('tr').find('input').index(this);
```

```js
$(document).on('keyup', 'input', function(event) {
  var inputListVal = $(this).closest('tr').find('input').index(this);
  console.log(inputListVal);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th><input type="text" name=""></th>
    <th><input type="text" name=""></th>
    <th><input type="text" name=""></th>
    <!-- I want this index if they are typing init -->
    <th><input type="text" name=""></th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Note: zero-based index

Answer (score 2):

Try this `$(this).parent('tr th').index();` And keyup event not working `class="inputs"` not there in your html .`tr th` its find the index of `th` from `tr`

```js
$(document).on('keyup', 'input', function(event) {
  var inputVal = $(this).val();
  var inputListVal = $(this).parent('tr th').index();
  console.log(inputListVal);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th><input type="text" name=""></th>
    <th><input type="text" name=""></th>
    <th><input type="text" name=""></th>
    <!-- I want this index if they are typing init -->
    <th><input type="text" name=""></th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).on('keyup', 'input', function(event) {
  var inputVal = $(this).val();
  var inputListVal = $(this).parent().index(); 
  console.log(inputListVal);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th><input type="text" name=""></th>
    <th><input type="text" name=""></th>
    <th><input type="text" name=""></th>
    <!-- I want this index if they are typing init -->
    <th><input type="text" name=""></th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).on('keyup', 'input', function(event) {
  var inputListVal = $('input').index(this);
  console.log(inputListVal);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th><input type="text" name=""></th>
    <th><input type="text" name=""></th>
    <th><input type="text" name=""></th>
    <!-- I want this index if they are typing init -->
    <th><input type="text" name=""></th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

> This is the Easiest Answer